# Dimensionality Reduction – PCA explanation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I don't think I have a good understanding of PCA, can someone help with my confusion below please?

Take iris dataset as an example, I have 4 covariates, x1:sepal length; x2:sepal width; x3:petal length; x4:petal width. And the formula can be seen below, a1,a2,a3,a4 are the weightings for the covariates. And PCA will try to maximise the variance using different linear transformations. While also follows the rule of a1^2 + a2^2 + a3^2 + a4^2=1. I'm interested in knowing the value of a1,a2,a3,a4.

```
a1*x1 + a2*x2 + a3*x3 + a4*x4
```

I have below code on python which I think is correct?

```
# load libraries
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
df = pd.DataFrame(X,columns=iris.feature_names)

pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components = 4)
digits_pca_4 = pca.fit(X)
digits_pca_4.explained_variance_ratio_
```

And the result is

```
array([0.92461872, 0.05306648, 0.01710261, 0.00521218])
```

My question is:

Am I correct to assume that a1=sqrt(0.92), a2=sqrt(0.05), a3=sqrt(0.02), a4=sqrt(0.005)?

Second question:

And if I were to choose the linear combination of a1=a2=a3=a4=0.5, what's the variance of this compared to the variance from the PCA (I'm assuming it's less than the PCA result since PCA maximise the variance?)? How can I get the variance of when a1=a2=a3=a4=0.5 in python? And is the variance from PCA the code below?

```
pca.explained_variance_.sum()
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer directly your question: **no, your initial interpretation is not correct**.

## Explanation

The actual projection done by PCA is a matrix multiplication `Y = (X - u) W` where `u` is the mean of X (`u = X.mean(axis=0)`) and `W` is the projection matrix found by PCA: a `n x p` orthonormal matrix, where `n` is the original data dimension and `p` the desired output dimensions. The expression you give (`a1*x1 + a2*x2 + a3*x3 + a4*x4`) does not mean anything with all values being scalars. At best, it could mean the calculation of a single component, using one column `j` of `W` below as the `a_k`: `Y[i, j] == sum(W[k, j] * (X[i, k] - u[k]) for k in range(n))`.

In any case, you can inspect all the variables of the result of `pca = PCA.fit(...)` with `vars(pca)`. In particular, the projection matrix described above can be found as `W = pca.components_.T`. The following statements can be verified:

```
# projection
>>> u = pca.mean_
... W = pca.components_.T
... Y = (X - u).dot(W)
... np.allclose(Y, pca.transform(X))
True

>>> np.allclose(X.mean(axis=0), u)
True

# orthonormality
>>> np.allclose(W.T.dot(W), np.eye(W.shape[1]))
True

# explained variance is the sample variation (not population variance)
# of the projection (i.e. the variance along the proj axes)
>>> np.allclose(Y.var(axis=0, ddof=1), pca. explained_variance_)
True
```

## Graphical demo

The simplest way to understand PCA is that it is purely a **rotation** in n-D (after mean removal) while retaining only the first p-dimensions. The rotation is such that your data's directions of largest variance become aligned with the natural axes in the projection.

Here is a little demo code to help you visualize what's going on. Please also read the [Wikipedia page on PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis).

```
def pca_plot(V, W, idx, ax):
    # plot only first 2 dimensions of W along with axes W
    colors = ['k', 'r', 'b', 'g', 'c', 'm', 'y']
    u = V.mean(axis=0)  # n
    axes_lengths = 1.5*(V - u).dot(W).std(axis=0)
    axes = W * axes_lengths  # n x p
    axes = axes[:2].T  # p x 2
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.scatter(V[:, 0], V[:, 1], alpha=.2)
    ax.scatter(V[idx, 0], V[idx, 1], color='r')
    hlen = np.max(np.linalg.norm((V - u)[:, :2], axis=1)) / 25
    for k in range(axes.shape[0]):
        ax.arrow(*u[:2], *axes[k], head_width=hlen/2, head_length=hlen, fc=colors[k], ec=colors[k])

def pca_demo(X, p):
    n = X.shape[1]  # input dimension
    pca = PCA(n_components=p).fit(X)
    u = pca.mean_
    v = pca.explained_variance_
    W = pca.components_.T
    Y = pca.transform(X)
    assert np.allclose((X - u).dot(W), Y)
    
    # plot first 2D of both input space and output space
    # for visual identification: select a point that's as far as possible
    # in the direction of the diagonal of the axes cube, after normalization
    # Z: variance-1 projection
    Z = (X - u).dot(W/np.sqrt(v))
    idx = np.argmax(Z.sum(axis=1) / np.sqrt(np.linalg.norm(Z, axis=1)))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 6))

    # input space
    pca_plot(X, W, idx, ax[0])
    ax[0].set_title('input data (first 2D)')

    # output space
    pca_plot(Y, np.eye(p), idx, ax[1])
    ax[1].set_title('projection (first 2D)')
    
    return Y, W, u, pca
```

## Examples

### Iris data

```
# to better understand the shape of W, we project onto
# a space of dimension p=3
X = load_iris().data
Y, W, u, pca = pca_demo(X, 3)
```

[image]

Note that the projection is really just `(X - u) W`:

```
>>> np.allclose((X - u).dot(W), Y)
True
```

### Synthetic ellipsoid data

```
A = np.array([
    [20, 10, 7],
    [-1, 3, 7],
    [5, 1, 2],
])
X = np.random.normal(size=(1000, A.shape[0])).dot(A)
Y, W, u, pca = pca_demo(X, 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but could you please answer directly to my questions in terms of iris dataset?
My two questions are 
My question is:

Am I correct to assume that a1=sqrt(0.92), a2=sqrt(0.05), a3=sqrt(0.02), a4=sqrt(0.005)?

Second question:

And if I were to choose the linear combination of a1=a2=a3=a4=0.5, what's the variance of this compared to the variance from the PCA (I'm assuming it's less than the PCA result since PCA maximise the variance?)? How can I get the variance of when a1=a2=a3=a4=0.5 in python? And is the variance from PCA the code below?

Comment: I tried to make my explanation clearer. Basically: no, the PCA projection cannot be simplified to just 4 scalar coefficients. Instead, it is a matrix multiplication. Please see the modified answer and see if you can get a better intuition that way.

Comment: This answer becoming nicer and nicer …

Comment: Thanks for the time you put in! I have read some other resources online and they finally click now.